# Conditional plotting by position in pgfplots groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, conditionals, etoolbox, groupplots

**Edit:** I was able to get the layout in the last image following the accepted answer. Just needs some visual tweaking now. I have some issues with compilation with LuaLatex, which I will troubleshoot but update this if I open another question.

I am trying to plot a matrix of probability densities (shown below) using pgfplots. The resulting figure is a lower-triangular matrix of plots, with normal line plots on the diagonal and filled contour plots below the diagonal. I figured the best way to do this would be to use `groupplot`.

I have data in files for each of the plots, and can plot them individually but can't figure out how to get them in the right position in the `groupplot`.

If `i` is columns and `j` is rows, then when `i>j` there should be no plot, when `i=j` there should be the line plot, and when `i<j` there is the countour plot.

I tried to write something that would match these conditions, then I can just add the correct call to the plots, but right now this code will not compile even with blank plots.

Based on values of `i` and `j`, I can call the files I need within a plot command, (e.g., `\addplot3[contour filled={number=14},mesh/rows=50] table {kde_2d_\i_\b.dat}`, where `b` is a modified value of `j` to get the plot in the right direction. I know that these plots work because I can plot them individually or in a group plot without any ordering, but the image won't compile once I include conditional statements.

Any tipss on where I should be looking to fix the issue?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} % LATEX and plain TEX
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 3},
    view={0}{90},
    try min ticks=2,
    max space between ticks=50,
    width=3.5cm,
    height=3.5cm]
    \def\myPlots{}
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,3}
    {
      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \j in {1,...,\i}
      {        
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{int(\j - 1)}
        \eappto\myPlots{%
          \ifnum\i=\j
            \noexpand\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot] % Line plot
          \else
            \ifnum\i>\j
                \noexpand\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot] % No plot
            \else
                \noexpand\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot] % Contour plot
            \fi
          \fi
        }
      }
    }
    \myPlots
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image: Using method laid out in accepted answer]

Comment: Why does `\j` run only up to `\i` **and** you add empty plots for `\i>\j`? Shouldn't `\j` run all the way to 3 instead?

Comment: Wow! :) ..........

Comment: I find this is interessting and I have some ideas. But what is the input-data-table (maybe in a simplified form)? Your MWE does not show one of your pictures. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various expansion issues. I ended up to use one loop instead of two to make it work.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\newcounter{irun}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 3},
    view={0}{90},
    try min ticks=2,
    max space between ticks=50,
    width=3.5cm,
    height=3.5cm]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in { % the following table is generated by a script
    1 / 1,
    1 / 2,
    1 / 3,
    2 / 1,
    2 / 2,
    2 / 3,
    3 / 1,
    3 / 2,
    3 / 3}{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\b{int(\theirun - 1)}
          \ifnum\i=\j
            \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot\noexpand\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};} % Line plot
            \temp
            \typeout{\i=\j}
          \else
            \ifnum\j>\i
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]} % No plot
                \temp
                \typeout{\j>\i}
            \else
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot\noexpand\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};} % Contour plot
                \temp
                \typeout{\j<\i}
            \fi
          \fi
    }
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I put some small plots just to show that this method discriminates between the diagonal, below and above.

Comment: This hasn't worked for me yet, I suspect it might be because I'm on pgfplots 1.14. Need to upgrade my MacTeX and test with the newer version of pgfplots.

Comment: @chasely Sorry to hear that. What error message do you get? And yes, upgrading pgfplots might be a good idea.

Comment: Looks like it was compiling with LuaLatex. I can get it to compile (with errors) with `pdflatex`, so I'll count this as being solved, but open another question if I can't figure out the compiling issues.

Comment: @chasely Strange. I compiled it with pdflatex.

Comment: Wow, sorry, it was late and that comment was completely wrong. I was having problems compiling with LuaLatex, which I was using because I was having the running out of memeory issues compiling with pdflatex due to the size of the data being plotted.

Comment: @chasely Yes, I confirm that there is an error occurring with lualatex. I am not an expert (in particular for lualatex), but the error message appears to be more severe than what we are doing here. You might ask a separate question on this, if you want. I have typeouts in the script, which show that under lualatex really crazy things like `1<1` happen. That is to say, it looks like the loop does not work under lualatex. It might be really worthwhile to bring this to the attention of Christian Feuersänger.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not know what the nature of the input data is, I will assume a very simple data table.

For the `groupplot`
I would just create an auxiliary table that contains entries `filled` and `first`. The groupplot entries can then easily be read out with a loop.

Hint: For the "stair-scheme" the number of input-values has to be of the kind `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28,... = n(n+1)/2`. 
So if the the input-data table has `N` rows, the number of rows (and columns) in a possible scheme can be calculated as the positive (integer) solution `n` of the quadratic equation  `N=n(n+1)/2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableset{
every head row/.style={  before row=\hline\rowcolor{gray!33}, after row=\hline },
every last row/.style={  after row=\hline },
schemerow/.style={
every row no #1/.style={   before row=\rowcolor{blue!44} },
}, 
firstrow/.style={
every row no #1/.style={   before row=\rowcolor{red!44} },
}, 
}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{count}% a counter that counts "filled" parts by 0,1,2,...

\section{Data-Table}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
No.    k
1      0.0
2      1.1
3      2.2
4      3.3
5      4.4
6      5.5
7      6.6
8      7.7
9      8.8
10     9.9
11    10.10
12    11.11
}\datatable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathsetmacro\datarows{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfmathsetmacro\schemerows{int(floor(0.5*(sqrt(8*\datarows+1)-1)))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\schemeentries{int(\schemerows*(\schemerows+1)/2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\schemeentriesno{\schemeentries-1}
% List for highligthing row: 
\let\List=\empty% create list
\foreach \n  in {0,...,\schemerows}
{%
\pgfmathparse{int(\n*(\n+3)/2}%  
  \ifx\empty\List{} \xdef\List{\pgfmathresult}%
  \else \xdef\List{\List,\pgfmathresult}%
  \fi
}

\schemerows
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
every even row/.style={  before row=\rowcolor{gray!33}   },
every odd row/.style={  before row=\rowcolor{gray!33}   },
schemerow/.list={0,...,\schemeentriesno},
firstrow/.list/.expand once={\List},
]{\datatable}

Number of rows in datatable: \datarows; \par
has to be of the kind $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28,\dots = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for scheme. \par
Number of (possible) schemerows: \schemerows.
Info: {\schemeentries} entries in scheme. \par
%List of highlighted row numbers: \List

\section{Help-Table}
\setcounter{count}{-1}
\def\helptablefilename{\jobname-helptable.txt}
\newwrite\helptableout
\immediate\openout\helptableout=\helptablefilename%
\immediate\write\helptableout{row, col, filled, first, count}
    
\foreach \row in {1,...,\schemerows}{%%
\foreach \col in {1,...,\schemerows}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\filled{\col<=\row ? 1 : 0}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\first{\col==\row ? 1 : 0}%
\ifnum\filled=1 \stepcounter{count} \fi
\immediate\write\helptableout{\row, \col, \filled, \first, \thecount}
}%
}%%
\immediate\closeout\helptableout
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{\helptablefilename}\helptable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\helptable}

\section{Groupplot}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\EndRowNo{\schemerows^2-1}
\setcounter{count}{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\pgfplotsset{
nowarnings/.style={xmin=-1, xmax=5, ymin=-1, ymax=10},
Paint/.style={draw=#1, 
%axis background/.style={fill=#1!44},
every axis plot/.style={draw=#1, very thick}
},
}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
group size={\schemerows} by {\schemerows}, 
%vertical sep=22mm, horizontal sep=22mm,
}, 
height=30mm, width=30mm,
title style={align=left},
ytick=data, 
%nowarnings,
]
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \helptablerow in {0,...,\EndRowNo}{%%
% Help
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\helptablerow}{filled}\of\helptable%
\pgfmathsetmacro\filled{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\helptablerow}{first}\of\helptable%
\pgfmathsetmacro\first{\pgfplotsretval}%
% Data
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\helptablerow}{count}\of\helptable%
\pgfmathsetmacro\datarow{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\datarow}{k}\of\datatable%
\pgfmathsetmacro\datavalue{\pgfplotsretval}%
% Plots:
\ifnum\filled=0 \edef\tmp{   
                    \noexpand\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]  
                    %\noexpand\addplot[]{0};
                    }\tmp
    \else 
       \ifnum\first=1
             \edef\tmp{    \noexpand\nextgroupplot[Paint=red]
                                  \noexpand\addplot[]{\datavalue};
                            }\tmp
      \else   
            \edef\tmp{    \noexpand\nextgroupplot[Paint=blue]
                                 \noexpand\addplot[]{\datavalue};
                           }\tmp
       \fi
\fi
}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```